# context menu with every right click vb.net

Tags: vb.net, treeview, behavior, right-click

I am trying to add a context menu to a treeview in vb.net but am not getting the desired behavior.  When I right click in the treeview I am able to get a context menu to appear with different options based on where the user clicks, but if the user clicks elsewhere in the treeview and a context menu is already up the context menu simply clears and does not reappear in the new clicked location (much like right clicking multiple times in a web browser).

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub treeviewMain_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles treeviewMain.MouseDown

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
       'Determine which tree structure is loaded in tree view.
        If (treeviewMain.Nodes.Item(0).Name = "MainNode") Then
            Test(sender, e)
        Else
            OtherTest(sender, e)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Test(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

    Dim Context As ContextMenu = New ContextMenu
    Dim NodeClicked As TreeNode

    NodeClicked = Me.tvwMain.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y)

    If NodeClicked Is Nothing Then
        Context.MenuItems.Add("New Item")
        Context.Show(treeviewMain, e.Location)
    ElseIf NodeClicked.Name = "MainNode" Then
        tvwMain.SelectedNode = NodeClicked
        Context.MenuItems.Add("New Item")
        Context.Show(treeviewMain, e.Location)
    ElseIf NodeClicked.Level = 0 And NodeClicked.Name <> "MainNode" Then
        tvwMain.SelectedNode = NodeClicked
        Context.MenuItems.Add("Rename")
        Context.MenuItems.Add("Delete")
        Context.MenuItems.Add("-")
        Context.MenuItems.Add("New")
        Context.Show(treeviewMain, e.Location)
    ElseIf NodeClicked.Level = 1 Then
        tvwMain.SelectedNode = NodeClicked
        Context.MenuItems.Add("Edit")
        Context.MenuItems.Add("Copy")
        Context.MenuItems.Add("Delete")
        Context.Show(treeviewMain, e.Location)
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there anyway to get this behavior in vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to write any code inside `MouseDown` event. What you just need to do is - to set the `ContextMenu` for each `Node` properly when you populate the `TreeView`.

If I were you, I would do something like this

```
    ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("New Item")

    ContextMenuStrip2.Items.Add("Rename")
    ContextMenuStrip2.Items.Add("Delete")
    ContextMenuStrip2.Items.Add("-")
    ContextMenuStrip2.Items.Add("New")

    ContextMenuStrip3.Items.Add("Edit")
    ContextMenuStrip3.Items.Add("Copy")
    ContextMenuStrip3.Items.Add("Delete")

    Dim mainNode As New TreeNode("Main Node")
    mainNode.Name = "MainNode"
    mainNode.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip1

    Dim level0Node As New TreeNode("Other Level 0 Node")
    level0Node.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip2

    Dim level1NodeOfMain As New TreeNode("Level 1 Node Under Main Node")
    level1NodeOfMain.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip3

    Dim level1NodeOfOther As New TreeNode("Level 1 Node Under Other Level 0")
    level1NodeOfOther.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip3

    mainNode.Nodes.Add(level1NodeOfMain)
    level0Node.Nodes.Add(level1NodeOfOther)

    treeviewMain.Nodes.Add(mainNode)
    treeviewMain.Nodes.Add(level0Node)

    treeviewMain.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip1 'you can remove this line if you don't want to show ContextMenu if user clicks not on the Nodes
```

Comment: I think I would still need to have code in the mouse down event to change the focus of the node on the right click.  Would something like this work?  <br/>`treeviewMain.Nodes.Add("CategoryID=" & row.Item(0).ToString, row.Item(1).ToString).ContextMenuStrip = test5`.  Im populating both level 0 and level 1 nodes from a table brought in as a datatable.

Comment: yes, it works. let's say, if _Main Node_ is selected and you right-click on _Other Level 0 Node_, then _Other Level 0 Node_ will get focus and selected and _ContextMenu_ will be shown

Comment: `treeviewMain.Nodes.Add("CategoryID=" & row.Item(0).ToString, row.Item(1).ToString).ContextMenuStrip = test5` is not correct!

You have create _Node_ object first, set _ContextMenu_ to it, then, add to the _TreeView_.

`Dim tmpNode As New TreeNode("CategoryID=" & row.Item(0).ToString, row.Item(1).ToString())` 
 `tmpNode.ContextMenuStrip = test5` 
 `treeviewMain.Nodes.Add(tmpNode)`